# Slider image hovering effect

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using clickable logo parade from http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/clickableLogoParade.html 
to do a logo slider.

Question1: How to make the image bigger upon hovering with the above logo slider?

I tried adjusting the image height and width directly, but I want the image to become bigger in this effect: http://www.morearty.com/blog/2013/06/06/html-css-to-make-an-image-bounce-to-a-larger-size-on-hover/

When one hovers over, the image position still stays in center.

Question2: Instead of having the above logo slider auto scroll, how to make it scroll only upon clicking to a arrow or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Question 1:

Give your images a class (for example `scrolling_image`) and on mouse over increase the size, and mouse out will return it back to normal:

```
$( "scrolling_image" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    "width": "300px",
    "height": "300px"
  }, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
$( "scrolling_image" ).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px"
  }, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

As for your second question, please read the [Documentation](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html#autoScrollingMode):

Comment: It's working! 
However when hovered over image, the image will be covered up by container. when i increase the size of the container, the last image goes to the next line.

Comment: add to your container and image this css: `position: relative;` then give your container `z-index: 1`; and your image `z-index: 2;` the z-index will make your image go above the container